# How do I effectively remove dog hair from carpets?

Tags: cleaning, home, pets, carpet

My dog's hair gets on surfaces like the carpets'. Its hard to get them off. I have to literally scratch the hair out or use brute force to remove it with a broom. I've tried vacuuming but it wasn't very effective. Are there better alternative solutions that is easier and less time consuming ?

Comment: Yes - buy a different vacuum and check the air watts (not the motor wattage) before buying. You need something with over 300 air watts, preferably around 350. Obviously not a hack...

Comment: @Bamboo buying an entirely new vacuum when I have a perfectly working vacuum just to get rid of my dog's hair from the carpet? Not exactly feasible . Im pretty sure there's an alternative :p

Comment: While there might be alternatives, a vacuum designed for pet hair would be my choice, unless this is only for a small area. While it will be an added expense, it would be worth it in time saved, to me at least. Though the squeegee idea is intriguing. Good luck, cause I know pet hair is really nasty to take care of.

Comment: @EroSennin I only suggest it cos that's what I had to do in the end, couldn't get my cat's or my own (long) hair off the carpet without hours of effort on hands and knees, got sick of it, gave in, bought another vacuum, this time checking the air watts before purchase. No probs now, comes up like tumbleweed!

Comment: Hmm .. I will have to take that measure if gets extreme :D . Thanks for the suggests guys :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An effective way to remove pet hair is to use a Squeegee!

[image]

I have..

- Long hair cat
- Short hair cat
- Border Collie puppy

all of which shed their fair amount of fur, and the Squeegee is by far the most reliable in picking fur off the carpet (more effective than my £280 Dyson :( ), especially if it has been left to lie for a few weeks.

Comment: nice. an alternative (works on uneven surfaces) : rubber gloves: put them on, and you'll be able to rub hairs out of anything

Comment: My brother uses the sole of his slippers, I think rubber but try it with all suitable footware in the house.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for the top answer (which is great for the floors) : you can put on rubber gloves (Like the pink ones you can buy in any stores), and then rub/brush off easily any hairs from any surfaces (sofas, etc. the floor too, but watch your posture ^^ ).