# How to effectively and regularly clean 1200sqft of carpet?

Tags: cleaning, carpet

I live in a ~1200 square feet (~110 square meters) apartment which has carpet (cable style, very plush) on the floors (except bathroom / kitchen).

I have a [bag-less Dirt Devil vacuum cleaner](http://dirtdevil.com/products/details/ud70107/breeze-cyclonic-upright/) which has a rotating brush.

Unfortunately, due to the size of the apartment the cleaner tends to overheat and shut down. Also, fairly quickly, the brush collects a lot of hair and [needs to be cleaned repeatedly](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2453/clean-hair-from-vacuum-brush).

I have seen a recommendation to [use a squeegee to remove the hair from the carpet](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/5739/how-do-i-effectively-remove-dog-hair-from-carpets). However, that only addresses the hair - and I wouldn't want to spend a day on my knees cleaning the entire carpet like that.

How can I effectively vacuum ~1200 square feet of carpet on a regular basis?

Answer (score 3):

Coming from a door to door vacuum salesman, I would have to bring up a point regarding standard retail store vacuum quality.

These vacuums are intended for basic cleaning, the beater bar and other components of a vacuum simply are not designed with standards. You can easily "kill" a ANY vacuum purchased at walmart, target, and other big retail stores in your area.

Kirby, FilterQueen, Electrolux and others are simply in a different breed of "Quality". If you are needing a vacuum that is going to hold up to your environment, and at the same time provide proper micron filtering (HEPA quality) to prevent indoor air pollution (HUGE DIFFERENCE with these vacuums stated above), you should serious invest in one of the higher quality vacuums. You should be able to find one of these in a local shop that specializes in "Vacuums". I would not shy from 2nd hand ones either as these vacuums are PROVEN to last many many many more years than your Dirt Devil or Dyson. (Do a good clean, replace ALL filters before using the vacuum inside your home if you buy a 2nd hand one).

GL

Answer (score 2):

> You could do a first pass with a stiff broom.

You can effectively sweep carpet and once the bulk of the hair is removed, follow with the vacuum.  Because it starts cleaner, the vacuum should be on for longer and not have to work as hard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another vacuum cleaner, switch between the two vacuum cleaners when one of them is overheating. And if it overheats take the other one and continue.

Or simply find a vacuum cleaner which doesn't overheat, I never had overheating problems.

About the problem with the brush which collects a lot of hair - this kind of bush is not suitable for homes where live people with long hair (or animals) maybe you have to try another one if you vacuum cleaner allows brush changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to invest in another vacuum, I suggest getting a robot vacuum. I personally own a Neato Botvac D75. There are other models too, some specifically good at collecting hair. According to the specs, it cleans on average 2000 sq feet. It doesn't need to be supervised and can return to docking station after done with the room. Another brand is Roomba. I got Neato because it has a planned path rather than going random directions, but if you are interested, you can go to their websites to compare and see which one you prefer.

Robot vacuums can be scheduled to automatically start cleaning on a regular basis. Therefore if you decide to invest in one, you will be hands free and have your carpet vacuumed every day.